# Django: foreign key to two models

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to build a app in Django. Let's say I have this model :

```
class Server(model.Models):
    hosted_by = models.ForeignKey('Self', limit_choices_to={'backup_server': True})
    host = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This class defines a server.

Each server can be a host, which means it can hosts other servers (virtual). 
So, Each server can be hosted by an other server. That's easy.

But here's the problem : a host can be part of a cluster of hosts. And so, a virtual server can be hosted by a standalone host, or by a cluster. When a server is hosted by a cluster, I don't want to specify by which host in the cluster.

I don't know how to manage the "hosted_by". I tried to use Contenttype and generic relations, but it was not user friendly at all in the admin section.

I created a new model :

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
```

So my Server is now like this :

```
class Server(model.Models):
    hosted_by = models.ForeignKey('Cluster' ...)
    host = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    member_of_cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster' ...)
```

Beside the fact that my Server in linked twice to Cluster (but with related_name it works), now a host can only be linked to a cluster...

Is there a easy, simple way to do something like :

```
hosted_by = models.ForeignKey('Self' OR 'Cluster', ...)
```

That would be usefull in my case :P

Anyway I'm kinda stuck with this. Of course I could do something like :

```
hosted_by_cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster' ...)
hosted_by_standalone_host = models.ForeignKey('Self', limit_choices_to={'backup_server': True})
host_standalone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
member_of_cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster' ...)
```

But I'm not sure I like the idea...

Also, before thinking seriously about this, I tried that each host would be in a cluster. So I would have cluster with only one hosts. I'm not sure either if it's a good idea.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: +1 for the 1 in 100 "new user question" that I don't have and answer to, and is actually comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few thoughts, I decided to go with the solution that every hosting server is in a cluster. That way I can add an other server to a cluster if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the default `not null` constraint on the foreign keys:

```
class Server(model.Models):
    hosted_by = models.ForeignKey('Self', blank=True, null=True, ...)
    host = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    member_of_cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster', blank=True, null=True, ...)
```

Then, create triggers on your DB to set the `hosted_by` column to `null` whenever a value is added or updated to `member_of_cluster`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_server
BEFORE INSERT ON server
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.member_of_cluster IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.hosted_by = NULL;
END IF;
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_update_server
BEFORE UPDATE ON server
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.member_of_cluster IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.hosted_by = NULL;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note** that I don't know what DB you are using, and the trigger syntax is written for MySQL, and that I am not sure if this is applicable to your situation, or if this is even a good idea in general.  This is simply what came to my mind.

Hope this helps!